# ASPNETCORE_URLS from docker-compose did not override appsetting.production.json

Tags: docker, asp.net-core

I configured my Asp.Net core project with compose-up.

And the secton for web is below:

```yaml
    server:
        container_name: 'server'
        image: 'mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0'
    #    restart: always
        working_dir: '/app'
        ports: 
            - "8886:80"
            - "8887:443"
        volumes: 
            - 'C:/Users/xx/Docker/meekou-server/:/app'
            - 'C:\Users\xx\Docker\meekou-certificates\https:/https/'
        environment: 
            - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production
            - ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:80
            - ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Password=test
            - ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Path=/https/aspnetapp.pfx
        entrypoint: 
            ["dotnet", "xx.Web.Host.dll"]           
        depends_on: 
            - meekou-mysql
```

And there is config from `appsettings.Production.json`

```json
  "Kestrel": {
    "Endpoints": {
      "Http": {
        "Url": "http://+:809"
      }
    }
  },
```

With `compose-up`, the asp.net core always listen under 809.

Is there any reason, the docker-compose file did not override the settings from appsettings.Production.json?

Answer (score 2):

The configuration in `appsettings.Production.json` takes precedence over the `ASPNETCORE_URLS` environment variable. More specifically, configuration in a `Kestrel` section overrides the `Urls` configuration setting.

If you override the configuration key that represents the Kestrel endpoint you've configured in `appsettings.Production.json`, using the `ASPNETCORE_KESTREL__ENDPOINTS__HTTP__URL` environment variable, it works:

```yaml
environment: 
    - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production
    - ASPNETCORE_KESTREL__ENDPOINTS__HTTP__URL=http://+:80
```

Comment: Normally environment variables take precedence over config file settings. Do you know why that isn't the case here?

Comment: @HansKilian It's less about configuration sources overriding others, and more about Kestrel preferring "endpoints" keys over the higher-level "urls" key. There's a test in the source that demonstrates this [here](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Servers/Kestrel/Core/test/AddressBinderTests.cs#L134-L158). You can follow that through the `AddressBinder.BindAsync` method to see more about how it works.

Comment: @KirkLarkin I made a test with `ASPNETCORE_KESTREL__ENDPOINTS__HTTP__URL` under .net 5, it seems it does not work. I am afraid I need to modify the `appsettings.Production.json`

Comment: @Edward try `Kestrel__EndPoints__Http__Url=http://+:80`, works for me